# 'aws s3 sync' only copy files with a certain extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket from which I would like to copy:

1. The entire directory structure (all directories and child directories, at any length)
2. Wherever they are in the directory structure, all files that match a certain file-name path (Eg: `*.log`, `*070719*.csv`, etc.)

Is there any way to do this from the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can.

Take a look at AWS CLI documentation: [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters):

> Currently, there is no support for the use of UNIX style wildcards in a command's path arguments. However, most commands have `--exclude "<value>"` and `--include "<value>"` parameters that can achieve the desired result. These parameters perform pattern matching to either exclude or include a particular file or object.
>
> For example, if the filter parameters passed to the command were:
>
> `--exclude "*" --include "*.txt"`
>
> All files will be excluded from the command except for files ending with `.txt`.

Comment: note to others: there's some sort of sequential processing and order required for these expressions. If you do `--include "*.txt" --exclude "*"` you get nothing.